# Open current file in IntelliJ wih Sublime

Tags: intellij-idea, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there any way to say that the currently selected file should be opened with Sublime or any other external editor?

I am aware of the Shortcut `Main Menu -> Navigate -> Select In... -> 8` to open the file in finder or any other suitable file explorer. From there I could open it in Sublime, though that's one step too much for me.

So any fancy makros / plugins who would directly open the file in Sublime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define [External Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/external-tools.html).

With `Right Click -> External Tools` you can open the file with sublime

Comment: You saved / made my day.